# Clutch overload flashing on display

Tags: clutch

Clutch overload is coming up on the dash of scania intermittently… clutch replaced six months ago

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question? Could you please edit your question and put further information in there so we understand what you'd like us to resolve?